# How to consider gravity as an entropic force?

Tags: physics, entropy

Is it possible to consider gravity as an entropic force?
What is mathematical relation between second law of thermodynamics and newton law of gravity?

Comment: You might get a more detailed answer from [physics.se](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, check out the following paper and video,

http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0785

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyomGtZCsmI